# After import to android studio, gradle task “app:dexDebug” fails

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have the following gradle file in my android app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test.forum"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

//configurations {
 //   all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
//}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19+'
    compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
}
```

and the bug output is Error code: 2; Output: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION.

When I uncomment the configurations part of the file I get Can't find package v4 (support) although I have it installed from the sdk. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: You're missing the `repositories {}` closure that defines where gradle should look for artifacts. Try adding the `buildcript { repositories { }}` section that from http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Simple-build-files

Comment: what is the output you see when running your gradle build from command line?